# MySQL foreign key data type error

Tags: mysql

I keep getting error on MySQL telling me to check datatypes.

I am trying to create fkey userid between the child and the parent table.

I have ensure that both my datatype as follows:

parent table

[image]

child table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In child table, attribute value is not mentioned for userid column, so by default it will get considered as 'SIGHNED' and primary key of parent table has default attribute value as 'UNSIGHNED'.

As per the MySQL manual, the sign of integer types must be the same.

Please check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: but it is "unsigned".